# How to declare correctly in VB?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, vba

I am new to VB. I read a book and follow its code

```
Public Class Form1

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim Wrap As String
    Wrap = Chr(13) & Chr(10)
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 1 To 4
        PictureBox1.Image = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile("C:\face0" & i & ".ico")
        MsgBox("Click for next face")
    Next
End Sub
End Class
```

It Works. However, I try to adjust the code to make Wrap become a variable available to the whole form1. I do the following, but it does NOT work. Why?

```
Public Class Form1

    Dim Wrap As String
    Wrap = Chr(13) & Chr(10)

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 1 To 4
        PictureBox1.Image = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile("C:\face0" & i & ".ico")
        MsgBox("Click for next face")
    Next
End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have arbitrary pieces of code at class level. `Wrap = Chr(13) & Chr(10)` is an arbitrary piece of code.

If you want to assign a value to a variable, do so with an initializer:

```
Dim Wrap As String = Chr(13) & Chr(10)
```

Better yet, use `ControlChars.CrLf` which is a predefined constant for same.

Answer (score 0):

Because you put code outside the function, only declare is allowed here.

Btw, Chr(13) & Chr(10) can be relaced by a really better version : vbCrLf
It's a constant, so you don't need to declare it, and it do exactly the same...